# Cannot access object passed into my DLL

Tags: c++, dll, function-pointers, msvcrt

I have been given the signature

```
typedef Trajectory* (__stdcall* Tcreate)(const Vector* v1, const Vector* v2);
```

and I need to be able to implement a DLL that calls a function named "create"

I created the function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) Trajectory* create(const Vector* v1, const Vector* v2)
{
    ...
}
```

In this function I try to access `v1`'s properties, such as `v1->x` but I am given the error:

> unable to evaluate the expression

when I try to inspect the variable via the debugger.

I suspect this may be a problem with the fact that I do not match create to the `__stdcall*` given in the `Tcreate`.

How do I just make a function based off of the `Tcreate` typedef that will allow me to access `v1` and `v2`'s properties?

Such as

```
__declspec(dllexport) Tcreate create(const Vector* v1, const Vector* v2)
{
}
```

Hopefully, if my function definition matches the exact signature, I can get the data in `v1` and `v2`!

Edit:
I have attempted to create the function as follows:
__declspec(dllexport) Object* __stdcall create(const Vector* v1, const Vector* v2)
{
...
}

It compiles, but when I do this, the executing program says it cannot find the function "create" and I assume it's using GetProcAddress, though I cannot know for sure as the exe has no debug information.

Comment: Does this function work or crashes? The reason of "unable to evaluate the expression" may be that debugger doesn't know anything about `Vector` type. Add the project which contains `Vector` to the solution. BTW, it is a good idea to declare `create` function as `__stdcall` to match typedef declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your response! The DLL does in fact crash, and the declaration of Vector is included in the DLL's header, so it does know what a vector is.
In regards to the __sdtcall being added in the function definition, when I do this the program tells me that it is unable to find the requested function - though I believe this is part of the problem.

Comment: `unable to find the requested function` Give more details about this: how Dll is loaded and how this function is called. You need also to declare `create` as `extern "C"` - verify with Dumpbin that function is exported without name mangling.

Comment: @AlexFarber create is in fact defined under an extern "C", just not included here, and I am actually unable to give more information as to how it is loaded by the executable, as I don't have access to the exe's source. Based on Albi's answer below, though, I feel like they may be loading it based on explicit linking? The signature they gave me though must be the key to creating a function that they will call, that will also be identical to their expected structure so I can access the vectors it passes pointers to.

Comment: Your __stdcall definition with Object and Point* doesn't match their typedef.

Comment: @AlexFarber Fixed, thank you. The problem does still stand, however.

Answer (score 0):

You should import the function in the caller with

```
 __declspec(dllimport) Trajectory* create(const Vector* v1, const Vector* v2);
```

It also depends on how your dll is loaded, explicit or implicit. Here is a good site describing it for MS C++

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yd93633.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse! I do suspect this is how it is done in the executable, but I do not have access to it, so I cannot tell. From the descriptions in the link, my guess is that they are using explicit linking. If this is the case, how do I go about getting my function loaded into the executable? And does the __stdcall make a difference in it being read by the executable? Thank you!

Comment: Hm, hard to say which calling convention is being used in the executable. Could you try   Trajectory* __stdcall create(const Vector* v1, const Vector* v2);

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1388/Calling-Conventions-Demystified   maybe helps to make the differences a bit clearer

Comment: With perfmon you can examine the loading and access of your dll.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion in your fist comment. When I implement the function as you suggested, I get an error from the exe saying that "the required function 'create' was not found". I also loaded the exe with "depends" so I could see which DLLs were required by the exe and my DLL. Is perfmon different? Will try and figure out how to do that, now.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean Procmon.exe, not perfmon.